# Is there a particular way to access the members of ChildViewController into ViewController, used else ways other than in function prepare(for: segue)?

Tags: ios, swift

Encountered logical problem while making a basic iOS application which demands **'ContainerView'**.

Added a label into the ChildView and named the label timerGaugeLabel.

```
@IBOutlet weak var timerGaugeLabel: UILabel!
```

(Unable to access the member into the ViewController class)

Used the function prepare(for : segue) and created the instance for segue locally inside the function.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ChildViewControllerSegue" {
            let childViewController = segue.destination as! ChildViewController
                    }
    }
```

(The data member timerGaugeLabel is accessible within the function but, not globally inside the ViewController.swift file)

Comment: Why do you need to access it in ViewController.swift?

Comment: The outlet is not connected yet in `prepare(for` anyway. Create a temporary property in the child view controller and assign the value to the label in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @Sweeper I have made the outlet of the label timerGaugeLabel in the ChildViewController.swift file. My containerView Storyboard ID is ChildViewController too.

Comment: @vadian So, we also need to connect the outlets into prepare(for :) 's?

Comment: No, the framework connects the outlets. The child view controller doesn’t even exist unless you instantiate it explicitly or retrieve it in `prepare(for`. But you didn’t answer Sweeper’s question. What is the goal to access the label in `ViewController`?

Comment: @vadian Like I said it in the comment aforementioned, I have made an outlet of timerGaugeLabel inside the ChildViewController.swift but, my ContainerView ID in Storyboard is ChildViewController; was not left with other option than making the outlet inside the same file or precisely, the ChildViewController class. Since, we can access members of another class into one as per OOPs concepts- decided to go with it.

Comment: @vadian `class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timerGaugeLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }`

Comment: @vadian `class ViewController: UIViewController {override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ChildViewControllerSegue" {
            let childViewController = segue.destination as! ChildViewController
            childViewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
        }
    }`

Comment: @vadian and Sweeper!  Now, I think that you have got the idea why I have created the outlet in ChildViewController. And, how can I access it in ViewController?